# Redmine and JIRA integration

Tags: integration, jira, redmine, bug-tracker

Is there a plugin for JIRA and Redmine which allows you to sync issues between the bugtrackers?

Scenario :
I create the issue in Redminie and analogous issue is created in jira.
Similarly, when creating issue with JIRA, I have a new one in Redmine. 
When changing the status of the issue in one of the bugtrack systems, 
changes are propagated to the other.

Ps. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

There is this
https://zapier.com/zapbook/jira/redmine/

although I havent tried it. In my expirience (connecting Jira with HPQC), connecting ALM tools is a ton of work and a lot of pain and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Currently this integration supports only new ticket propagation from one system to the other. It does not support status updates.

Answer (score 1):

TaskAdapter ([www.taskadapter.com](http://www.taskadapter.com)) supports two-way transfer between Atlassian JIRA and Redmine, including task status.